# ¿Cómo seleccionar un elemento por defecto en Listbox Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

He creado un `Listbox` en `Tkinter` y quiero un elemento esté seleccionado por defecto, no solo que tenga el foco, sino que esté seleccionado.

He probado con `.selection_set(0)` y lo resalta, no lo selecciona. Al cambiar a otro `widget` ya no aparece el elemento resaltado. He visto la posibilidad de añadir el evento:

```
self.lstbox_tipo_rosca.event_generate("<<ListboxSelect>>")
```

pero no acabo de ententer. Imagino que crear un bind, pero no lo veo claro. Por favor, ¿me podeis ayudar?. Agradecido de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Amplío la información y añado un ejemplo. Información: Por defecto una provincia está seleccionada, está resaltada. Al pasar de una entrada a otra con <kbd>Tab</kbd> desaparece la selección del `Listbox`.

Lo mismo pasa si no utilizo la tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd>, pero señalo una entrada con el cursor para editarla.

Yo quisiera que, de alguna manera, el elemento seleccionado del `Listbox` apareciera marcado, resaltado, y no fuera necesario añadir una etiqueta para ver el elemento seleccionado.

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ejemplo listbox y scrollbar

import tkinter as tk
def cargaTupla():
    tplaParaLstbox =  ('ÁLAVA', 'ALBACETE', 'ALICANTE', 'ALMERÍA', 'ASTURIAS',
                  'ÁVILA', 'BADAJOZ', 'BARCELONA', 'BURGOS', 'CÁCERES', 'CÁDIZ', 'CANTABRIA',
                  'CASTELLÓN', 'CEUTA', 'CIUDAD_REAL', 'CÓRDOBA', 'CUENCA', 'GERONA', 
                  'GRANADA', 'GUADALAJARA', 'GUIPÚZCOA', 'HUELVA', 'HUESCA', 'ISLAS_BALEARES',
                  'JAÉN', 'LA_CORUÑA', 'LA_RIOJA', 'LAS_PALMAS', 'LEÓN', 'LÉRIDA', 'LUGO',
                  'MADRID', 'MÁLAGA', 'MELILLA', 'MURCIA', 'NAVARRA', 'ORENSE', 'PALENCIA',
                  'PONTEVEDRA', 'SALAMANCA', 'SEGOVIA', 'SEVILLA', 'SORIA', 'TARRAGONA',
                  'TENERIFE', 'TERUEL', 'TOLEDO', 'VALENCIA', 'VALLADOLID', 'VIZCAYA', 'ZAMORA',
                  'ZARAGOZA')
    return tplaParaLstbox


class LstboxEnsayo:
   def __init__(self, parent, listaValores):
      self.listaValores = listaValores
      indice_def=2
      #crea frames
      frame_0_0 = tk.Frame(parent)
      frame_0_0.grid(row=0, column=0)
      frame_1_0 = tk.Frame(parent)
      frame_1_0.grid(row=1, column=0)
      #
      self.creaLstBox(frame_0_0, self.listaValores, indice_def)
      self.creaLbl(frame_1_0, indice_def)
      self.creaEnt(frame_1_0)
      # Muestra con bind el elemento seleccionado
      self.lstbox_1.bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.mstraElemSelec)

   def creaLstBox(self, parent, listaVisualizar, indice_def):
      #Crea scrollbar
      scrllbar_1 = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient = 'vertical')
      #Crea listbox
      self.lstbox_1 = tk.Listbox(parent, height = 5)

      scrllbar_1['command'] = self.lstbox_1.yview # Controla scroll vertical
      self.lstbox_1['yscroll'] = scrllbar_1.set #enlaza con el metodo de scrollbar

      #carga elementos de la tupla
      self.lstbox_1.insert('end', *listaVisualizar)

      scrllbar_1.pack(in_=parent, side='right', fill='y')
      self.lstbox_1.pack(in_=parent, side='left', fill='both', expand='y')
      self.lstbox_1.selection_set(indice_def) #selecciono un elemento por defecto

   def mstraElemSelec(self, evento):
      indice = int(self.lstbox_1.curselection()[0])
      elemento = self.lstbox_1.get(indice)
      self.sel_prov_strvar.set(elemento)

   def creaLbl(self, parent, indice_def):   
      lbl_1 = tk.Label(parent, text="Introduce zona: ", anchor='e', width=20)
      lbl_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
      lbl_2 = tk.Label(parent, text="Introduce calificacion: ", anchor='e',  width=20)
      lbl_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
      lbl_3 = tk.Label(parent, text="Provincia seleccionada: ", anchor='e',  width=20)
      lbl_3.grid(row=2, column=0)
      #
      self.sel_prov_strvar = tk.StringVar()
      pordefecto=self.lstbox_1.get(indice_def)
      self.sel_prov_strvar.set(pordefecto)
      lbl_4 = tk.Label(parent, textvariable=self.sel_prov_strvar, anchor='e',  width=10)
      lbl_4.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def creaEnt(self, parent):
      entrada1 = tk.Entry(parent, width=10)
      entrada1.grid(row=0, column=1)
      entrada2 = tk.Entry(parent, width=10)
      entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__=="__main__":
   vtna_ppal=tk.Tk()
   vtna_ppal.geometry("230x200")
   tpla_a_visualizar  = cargaTupla()
   LstboxEnsayo(vtna_ppal, tpla_a_visualizar)
   vtna_ppal.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, estabas bastante cerca, no creo que sea necesario el uso de:

```
self.lstbox_tipo_rosca.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')
```

Basta con setear el parámetro [`exportselection`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-exportselection) a `False` al crear el `Listbox`:

```
self.lstbox_1 = tk.Listbox(parent, height=5, exportselection=False)
```

Con esto evitas que se deseleccione el item al perder el foco en el widget.

Comment: Solo puedo decir.... GRACIAS !!!!!! Es tonto, pero a veces hasta que el GUI no te queda como tu quieres no hay manera de avanzar. PERFECTO!!! ... y simple !!